# What does exit(0) do inside a recursive function?

Tags: recursion

Is there any way to exit a program inside a resursive function ? If there is a way, What will happen if I exit like that ? what does exit(0) with in a recursive function actually do ?

Comment: That will indeed exit the program. Do you have any reason to suspect it wouldn't?

Comment: Exit is the ultimate continuation but it smells bad design. Have you found it or are you planning to solve somthing with this?

Comment: You should probably add a language tag to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exit(0)` will always* make the entire application exit immediately (with a status code of 0). Whether you're calling it from a recursive function or not is irrelevant — it's completely different from `return`.

*: well, almost always; there are a few crazy situations where it won't, but that's besides the point

Comment: What happens to the recursion stack in memory if the program ends abruptly inside recursion with exit(0) ?

Comment: The stack is part of the current process's address space, and it disappears along with everything else in there when the process exits.